# wanted to know pid for outcome of script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wait, pid

./abcd.sh #this script is responsible to run a java code for creating a zip file in /tmp/abcd/

Some times abcd.sh script takes 30 seconds to create a zip file and some times it takes 60 seconds to create.

Since i don't have permission to edit abcd.sh file, I wrote this code to get pid for ./abcd.sh, but dont know how to get the pid for its child process.

```
./abcd.sh &
pid=$!
wait $pid
```

This code is waiting till the ./abcd.sh executes, but its not waiting till the zip file is complete.

Is there any way where it can wait till the zip file creates? my idea is, if we get to know the pid of zip file creation we can use wait $zipfilepid, but not sure how to get the pid for zip file creation.

```
.abcd.sh 
sleep 60
```

I know **sleep** is an alternative for this, but i don't want to wait even if the zip file is created.

Comment: You are editing the wrong script.  It will be much easier and more robust to change `abcd.sh` so that it waits for the zip file to complete.  You cannot reliably wait for a process that is not your child.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't have permissions to edit abcd.sh file?

Comment: Why not remove the `&` the script will wait automatically.

Comment: I tried that as well : `./abcd.sh wait`

Comment: yeah, doesn't solve the problem, but still better than `&`

Comment: you can get the children pids if you really want it, but would be better to copy abcd.sh and edit it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the "zip" program, you can find it in the process list and then determine its process ID.  Assuming the name of the process you're waiting on is simply "zip", you can use something like this:

```
PROCNAME="zip"
PROCRUN=`ps h -ef|egrep -e "$PROCNAME"|grep -v " $$ "`
PIDS=`echo "$PROCRUN"|tr -s " "|cut -d" " -f2`
wait $PIDS
```

This will work for multiple PIDs.  you may need to alter the `PROCNAME` variable's value to better target a specific process, such as:

```
PROCNAME=" zip "
PROCNAME="zip name-of-file-to-zip"
PROCNAME="zipscriptname"
```

...etc.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for not telling this upfront, zip file is created by a java code and abcd.sh is calling that java code to create a zip file.

Comment: @phani - as long as you can run a shell script, you can still grab the process ID of the java code you're calling and wait for it to complete.  You only need to know the command-line text for the process as it appears in a `ps -ef` command.  If you're running java to execute the command, it may look something like `java -cp zipstuff.jar com.domain.mystuff`, so that is the string you would use for `PROCNAME`.  Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, i came to a conclusion that this approach may not be possible because i dont have control over the java code that creating a zip file and shell script(abcd.sh) that is instantiating to run the java code.

The approach that i took is:

1. find out whether zip file is still writing/open  using `/usr/sbin/lsof /path/to/zip/abcd.zip`, with this command i will `$? 0` if file is writing/open, i get `$? 1` if file completed/close.
2. put `$?` into while loop and if `$? -eq 0` go for sleep else exit the program.

`/usr/sbin/lsof /path/to/zip/abcd.zip

rc=$?

while [ $rc -eq 0 ]

do

echo "Zip file is still creating, sleeping for 3 seconds"

sleep 3

done`

Please let me know if you have better approach.